# Query an XML based on a column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I want to query an XML based on a column value in SQL.

My XML is as follows

```
declare @xmlValue xml = 
'<Accounts>
 <Account>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <Age>10</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Richard</Name>
    <Age>12</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Shane</Name>
    <Age>15</Age>
  </Account>
</Accounts>';
```

Now I know I can query the XML on Id, if I have a constant Id like this:

```
select @xmlValue.query('/Accounts[1]/Account[./ID/text()="2"]');
```

Also, I can use `sql:variable` like below, in case I have a variable:

```
declare @ID int
set @ID = 1
select @xmlValue.query('/Accounts[1]/Account[./ID/text()=sql:variable("@ID")]');
```

Now, I have a table `#tmpTable` with an xml column (named `xmlValue`). 
I want to query the `#tmpTable` with join to `Account` table and get the AccountId from there, somewhat like this:

```
-- This does not work
select xmlValue.query('/Accounts[1]/Account[./ID/text()=a.AccountId]') as XMLResult 
from #tmpTable tmp
inner join Accounts a on tmp.Id = a.Id
where a.Active = 1
```

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
select xmlValue.query('/Accounts[1]/Account[./ID/text()=sql:column("a.AccountId")]') as XMLResult 
from #tmpTable tmp
inner join Accounts a on tmp.Id = a.Id
where a.Active = 1
```

`sql:column()` is - similar to `sql:variable()` - the appropriate way to introduce a column's value into an `XQuery`